# how to change color of circle according to percentage

Tags: android

I want to show the percentage of humidity in circle.and change the color of circle dynamically accroding to percentage of humidity.
I had created following layout.Created two drawable with two different color also.[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/registration_bg"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_layout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/circleheight"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/circleheight"
        android:background="@drawable/circle1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/image_level"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/circleheight"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/circleheight"
            android:background="@drawable/circle2"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my mai layout file

following are two drawable files

```
circle1.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/circle1"
        android:endColor="@color/circle1"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>

circle2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/circle2"
        android:endColor="@color/circle2"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: see `GradientDrawable` docs

Comment: can you specify some hint plz

Comment: i tried with GradientDrawable .its not working..i need oval shape

Comment: do you know how to get "android:background" property in java code?

Comment: yes..:-) i had done that

Comment: so what kind of `Drawable` do you get for image_level or image_layout?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91902/discussion-between-asiya-and-pskink).